# Node.JS blocking data event

Tags: javascript, node.js, client-server, tcpclient

I start using Node.js 4 hours ago and i'm not sure about the non-blocked function.

I write a server in Node.JS and he need to handle many clients in C# throught TCP and I don't want a client wait 5 mins before he get an answer from the server.

I try this code with 2 clients and when with the 1st one, I try to send a huge file (to look if the second can do some request), the second try to connect and only recieve the id to say connection established after the transfert (Actually after Visual Studio crash because my C# client can't send huge file without crashing after like 30 seconds..)

I try to use sleep.sleep(5000) to test but he jump hover so I don't know how to test if it block or not and how to make it non-blocked

Thanks and sorry for my poor english I speak french

Here's my server :

```
net = require('net');
fs = require('fs');
mysql = require('mysql');

var client = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '*****',
  database : 'test',
});

var clients = [];

function clientStruct() 
{
    this.id;
    this.soc;
    this.lastCommand;
}

var id = 0;

//?? Difference between Server and createServer
var s = net.createServer(function(socket) {

    var client = new clientStruct();
    client.id = id++;
    client.soc = socket;
    clients.push(client);

    var stream = null;

    socket.write(client.id + '\n');

    socket.on('data', function(msg_sent)
    {
        var msg = msg_sent.toString().split(' ');

        if (msg[0] == '-command')
        {
            client.lastCommand = null;
        }

        if (client.lastCommand == 'modifyProfilePic')
        {
            stream.write(msg_sent);
            client.lastCommand = 'writeFile';
            socket.write('0\n');
            console.log('WRITE THE FILE');

            sleep.sleep(5000);
            console.log('sleep for 5 sec');
        }
        else if (client.lastCommand == 'writeFile')
        {
            if (msg_sent == '\n')
                console.log('END');
            else
                stream.write(msg_sent);

            //console.log(msg_sent.toString());
        }

        //FIRST ARGUMENTS
        else if (msg[1] == 'mkuser')
        {
            socket.write('0\n');
            client.lastCommand = msg[1];
        }
        else if (msg[1] == 'modifyProfilePic')
        {
            stream = fs.createWriteStream('test2.mp4', { flags : 'w' });
            socket.write('0\n');
            client.lastCommand = msg[1];
        }
        else
        {
            socket.write('1\n');
            console.log('error');
            client.lastCommand = null;
        }
    });

    socket.on('end', function() {
        var i = clients.indexOf(socket);
        console.log('END of client ' + client.id + ' index ' + i + ' tab size ' + clients.length);
        clients.splice(i, 1);
    });

    socket.on('error', function() {
        var i = clients.indexOf(socket);
        console.log('ERROR of client ' + client.id + ' index ' + i + ' tab size ' + clients.length);
        clients.splice(i, 1);
    });

});

var PORT = 10001
s.listen(PORT);
console.log('System waiting at localhost port:' + PORT)
```

Answer (score 1):

your code looks common, but i think you are abusing the `stream` variable, i see it gets assigned, in a line of code, and then reused through all code in sync, no callbacks to determinate that the chunk `stream.write(...)` has successfully been written or not.

> writable.write(chunk, [encoding], [callback])#
>
> - chunk Buffer | String Data to be written
> - encoding String Optional. If chunk is a string, then encoding defaults to 'utf8'
> - callback Function Optional. Called when this chunk is successfully written.
> - Returns Boolean

so a piece of "async" code would look like

```
stream.write(msg_sent,"ascii"/* or other encoding*/,function(){
 console.log("File write success");
 // continue code here.
});
```

Try reading the documentation about, `Streams` and `fs.createWritableStream`.